# OpenSSL error impossible to verify SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, npm, openssl, self-signed-certificate

I installed OpenSSL and tried to use it to verifiy my SSL certificates with the commands shown in [this page](https://support.yourwebhoster.eu/en-us/article/30-how-to-verify-ssl-certificates-with-openssl-on-command-line) but I always get this error:

```
s_client -connect server.yourwebhoster.eu:995 
18556:error:2008F002:BIO routines:BIO_lookup_ex:system lib::0:H connect:errno=11001 error in s_client
```

I want to verify these certificates because I'm block when I try to run a program with node js that uses a https.get request :
[image: Error from execution]

I searched solution on the Internet and I found out that line : `npm config set strict-ssl false`

I tried it, set it to true then to false again but nothing changed,

Comment: could you post the exact command you are using please

Comment: for this error I used the command : openssl s_client -connect server.yourwebhoster.eu:21 -starttls ftp

Comment: same for me: openssl s_client -showcerts -servername registry.npmjs.org -connect registry.npmjs.org:443
34359738384:error:2008F002:BIO routines:BIO_lookup_ex:system lib:crypto/bio/b_addr.c:726:Name or service not known
connect:errno=88

Comment: in my case 'npm config set strict-ssl false' was ok to perform npx ng update